# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value

Tags: java, database-connection

And my code is:

```
        try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;jithin-pc:1433;databaseName=news;IntegratedSecurity=true");
        String qr="SELECT * FROM base";
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(qr);
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        out.println(rs.getString(1));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            out.println(e);
        }
```

i am getting an error as below:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.
```

i tried changing sql settings firewall etc. pls any suggestions

Comment: isn't this SQL server Express version ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jithin-pc is localhost just localhost or jithin-pc should be enough.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=news;IntegratedSecurity=true
jdbc:sqlserver://jithin-pc;databaseName=news;IntegratedSecurity=true
```

Also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: but its not working; But finally i found a way out Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:jithin","username","password");
            //now go to administrative tools in control panel and add sql driver....!! THANKS 4 the post

Comment: He needs to escape the hostname not change it